# passing collections as parameters with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been using parameters to query node indexes as such (using the rest api in java)-

```
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start nd=node:name_index(name={src}) return nd.age as age", MapUtil.map("src", "Susan");
```

However I haven't been able to get this to work for a collection of nodes/names. I have been trying something along the lines of-

```
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start nd=node:name_index(name={src}) return nd.age as age", MapUtil.map("src", Arrays.asList("Susan","Brian", "Ian"));
```

But it refuses to compile. I as wondering if there is something wrong in my syntax or that parameters are not designed to work in this context.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I am using neo4j 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The `name=` syntax in the start is meant to do an index lookup on a property. It won't do an `IN` lookup. The way you can do this sort of lookup is like this (note it depends on Apache's StringUtils):

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Susan","Brian", "Ian");
String luceneQuery = "name:("+StringUtils.join(names, ",")+")";
engine.query("start nd=node:name_index({luceneQuery}) return nd.age as age", MapUtil.map("luceneQuery", luceneQuery));
```

Just a note, this is the "legacy" index way of doing things. In 2.0 they've introduced label-based indexes, which work entirely differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot; though it would still only return a non empty answer when I added a space after the comma in line 2.  I used-

String luceneQuery = "name:("+StringUtils.join(names, ", ")+")";

and it returned the age of one person. When I tried this:

```
String luceneQuery = "fs:(fs:"+ StringUtils.join(names, " OR fs:")+")";
```

it gave me all three ages. However, I am still unsure about whether this query will be able to leverage the usual advantages of parameters , i.e. will the engine be able to reuse the query and execution path the next time around (this time we may want to query for 4 names instead of 3)